# Spring Framework NString not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have an object named "Duuni" with some abstract getter and setter methods inside and "DuuniImpl" implementation of Duuni. I use JdbcTemplate and RowMapper to retreive data from database. Here's my code:

```
package vjb.de.vietjob.bean;

import java.util.Date;

public interface Duuni {

    public abstract int getId();
    public abstract void setId(int id);

    public abstract String getNimi();
    public abstract void setNimi(String nimi);

    public abstract Date getPaiva();
    public abstract void setPaiva(Date paiva);

    public abstract String getTiedot();
    public abstract void setTiedot(String tiedot);

    public abstract String getPaikka();
    public abstract void setPaikka(String paikka);

    public abstract String getPalkka();
    public abstract void setPalkka(String palkka);



}
```

And DuuniImpl class:

```
package vjb.de.vietjob.bean;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DuuniImpl implements Duuni {
    SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    private int id;
    private String nimi;
    private Date paiva;
    private String tiedot;
    private String paikka;
    private String palkka;


    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNimi() {
        return this.nimi;
    }

    public void setNimi(String nimi) {
        this.nimi = nimi;
    }

    public Date getPaiva() {
        return paiva;
    }

    public void setPaiva(Date paiva) {
        this.paiva = paiva;
    }

    public String getTiedot() {
        return this.tiedot;
    }

    public void setTiedot(String tiedot) {
        this.tiedot = tiedot;
    }

    public String getPaikka() {
        return this.paikka;
    }

    public void setPaikka(String paikka) {
        this.paikka = paikka;
    }

    public String getPalkka() {
        return this.palkka;
    }

    public void setPalkka(String palkka) {
        this.palkka = palkka;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "duuniIplm [id=" + id + ", nimi=" + nimi + ", paiva=" + paiva
                + ", tiedot=" + tiedot + ", paikka=" + paikka + ", palkka="
                + palkka + "]";
    }


}
```

DuuniDaoImpl class:

```
package vjb.de.vietjob.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import vjb.de.vietjob.bean.Duuni;



@Repository
public class DuuniDaoImpl implements DuuniDao {

    @Inject
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }



    public List<Duuni> showDuuni() {
        String sql = "select * from duuni";
        RowMapper<Duuni> duuniRM = new DuuniRowMapper();
        List<Duuni> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, duuniRM);
        return list;
    }

    public void postDuuni(Duuni duuni) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void deleteDuuni(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void postDuuni() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

DuuniRowMapper class:

```
package vjb.de.vietjob.dao;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import vjb.de.vietjob.bean.*;
public class DuuniRowMapper implements RowMapper<Duuni> {

    public Duuni mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
        Duuni duuni = new DuuniImpl();
        duuni.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        duuni.setNimi(rs.getString("nimi"));
        duuni.setPaikka(rs.getString("paikka"));
        duuni.setPaiva(rs.getDate("paiva"));
        duuni.setPalkka(rs.getString("palkka"));
        duuni.setTiedot(rs.getNString("tiedot"));

        return duuni;
    }

}
```

And finally the application to handle data from database:

```
package vjb.de.vietjob.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import vjb.de.vietjob.bean.Duuni;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("vietjob-data.xml");
        DuuniDao dao = (DuuniDao) context.getBean("duuniDao");
        List<Duuni> d = dao.showDuuni();
        for(Duuni duuni : d){
        System.out.println(duuni.getNimi());
        }
        context.close();

    }

}
```

But when I'm runnig it, the error comes with "NString not supportted":

```
0    [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@504bae78: startup date [Mon Mar 07 17:25:45 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
60   [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [vietjob-data.xml]
385  [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  - Loading properties file from URL [file:/Volumes/Data/JavaEE/workspace/vietjob/target/classes/db_connection.properties]
635  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
719  [main] INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory  - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: StatementCallback; SQL [select * from duuni]; NString not supported; nested exception is java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: NString not supported
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:416)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:471)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:481)
    at vjb.de.vietjob.dao.DuuniDaoImpl.showDuuni(DuuniDaoImpl.java:35)
    at vjb.de.vietjob.dao.test.main(test.java:14)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: NString not supported
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.getFeatureNotSupportedException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:165)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLResultSet.getNString(MySQLResultSet.java:2679)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getNString(DelegatingResultSet.java:802)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getNString(DelegatingResultSet.java:802)
    at vjb.de.vietjob.dao.DuuniRowMapper.mapRow(DuuniRowMapper.java:17)
    at vjb.de.vietjob.dao.DuuniRowMapper.mapRow(DuuniRowMapper.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:460)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:405)
    ... 4 more
```

I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: Could be issue with the `jdbc` driver you are using. See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getNString-java.lang.String-  You get this exception if if the JDBC driver does not support `getNString(String columnLabel)` method

Comment: I use the lastest version of JDBC, it's 4.1.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rs.getString("tiedot")` instead of `rs.getNString("tiedot")` because MariaDB Connector/J does not support it.

Comment: It's correct, thanks. Don't know why i use it because it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of MariaDB client.

According to [this jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-300), the issue is fixed.